# Ant version wrongly picked with weblogic 10.3.6.0

Tags: ant, version, weblogic11g

I have installed Weblogic 10.3.6.0 and using apache-ant-1.8.1 for build. ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME are set

When I ran diagnostics I get this part

```
-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
ant.java.version: 1.6
ant.core.lib: C:\BEA11\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1\lib\ant.jar
ant.home: C:\apps\apache-ant-1.8.1
```

Ant home is 1.8 but the core lib is referring older version. Is there any way to override this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT

after adding ant\bin location to PATH, I get different problem.

```
 taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Solution : mentioned the weblogic server path properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet the older version is bundled with WebLogic.

See if you can find it to confirm.

I'd argue that the WebLogic version ought to be sufficient.  What functionality is it missing that you can't do without?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13750/anttasks.htm

Comment: Yes, I added the higher version in PATH and this problem is over. Thanks.